# Understanding であるだけに

Tags: grammar

From the beginning of 銀河英雄伝説１

> 西暦二八〇一年、太陽系第三惑星地球からアルデバラン系第二惑星テオリアに政治的統一の中枢を遷し、銀河連邦の成立を宣言した人類は、同年を宇宙暦一年と改元し、銀河系の深奥部と辺境部にむかってあくなき膨張を開始した。西暦二七〇〇年代のいちじるしい特徴である戦乱と無秩序とが、外的世界への人類の発展を停滞させた**あとであるだけに**、そのほとばしるエネルギーはいっそう、爆発的であった。

I have trouble understanding how であるだけに works in the last sentence. I assume the basic structure of the last sentence is「AあとであるだけにB」. It is similar to「AあとB」which means "After A happened, B happens." But what nuance does であるだけに add after あと? Does it imply B happens only because A happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [だけに](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%AB/#jn-136140) is used in the sense that

> …であるから、なおのこと。「期待が大きかった―失望も大きかった」.

So the last sentence means

- **Because (2801 was) after** wars and disorder in 2700s stagnated human expansion,
- the ほとばしる energy was **all the more** explosive

(**bold** corresponds to あとであるだけに)

Comment: Ah thanks! I missed the "2801 was" part which caught me off guard.